# access service fields AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, get

I have an AngularJS factory to retrieve some data:

```
angular.module('App').factory('AppFactory', function($resource) {
return $resource('rest/kpi/getData/:id',{},{
    'get' : {isArray:true}

})
```

})

After I made a get request for my data is there a way to access certain fields without making another get request ?

Comment: you would be able to access all data returned by the call. Which data fields you are talking about.

Comment: a random field returned from my call. Can I do something like $scope.data = AppFactory.random_field ? Is that valid ?

Comment: Yes check below For simplified code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do below:

```
angular.module('App').factory('AppFactory', function($resource) {
  return $resource('rest/kpi/getData/:id')
   })
})
```

In controller:

```
 angular.module('App').controller('ctrl',function(AppFactory){
     AppFactory.get().$promise.then(function(value) {
        $scope.data = value.random_filed;
    });

})
```